# ctypes load a dll without error message, but nothing happened

Tags: c++, python, dll, ctypes

I tried to use windll.LoadLibrary in ctypes to import a dll file into python. Though there wasn't any error message, none of the functions listed in the header file seemed to be successfully loaded. I wonder if there is anything wrong with the dll file, or I have used the windll.LoadLibrary method incorrectly.

The dll and header files can be downloaded from the following link:
http://www.cc.ncu.edu.tw/~auda/ATC3DG.rar

The python commands I used was:

```
from ctypes import * 
libc=windll.LoadLibrary('ATC3DG.DLL')
```

The results can be viewed from the following link, which shows dir(libc) does not give me any functions or variables listed in ATC3DG.h:

http://www.cc.ncu.edu.tw/~auda/ATC3DG.jpg

I am using python 2.7.3 (32-bit), and ipython 0.13.1 on a windows 7 (64-bit) platform.

thanks,

Erik Chang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't show up when you use `dir` unless you've already accessed the function. For example:

```
In [98]: from ctypes import cdll

In [99]: libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')

In [100]: dir(libc)
Out[100]:
['_FuncPtr',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_func_flags_',
 '_func_restype_',
 '_handle',
 '_name']

In [101]: libc.printf
Out[101]: <_FuncPtr object at 0x65a12c0>

In [102]: dir(libc)
Out[102]:
['_FuncPtr',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_func_flags_',
 '_func_restype_',
 '_handle',
 '_name',
 'printf']
```

You can see why this happens by looking at the `CDLL.__getitem__` and `CDLL.__getattr__` methods:

```
class CDLL(object):
    # ...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
            raise AttributeError(name)
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
        setattr(self, name, func)
        return func

    def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
        if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, (int, long)):
            func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal
        return func
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I tried to call the function prototyped in the header file:

ATC3DG_API int InitializeBIRDSystem(void);

with the following commands:

Comment: Try actually calling a function, e.g., `libc.GetSystemStatus()`. What happens?

Comment: You also might want to call it something besides `libc`, since `libc` should be reserved for a library called `libc`. What about calling it `libatc` instead?

Comment: The functions in that DLL are all cdecl. Use `atc3dg = cdll.atc3dg`. The symbol names are [decorated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2k2877b.aspx) in both the MS C++ and `__cdecl` styles, i.e `?GetSystemStatus@@YAKXZ` and `_GetSystemStatus`.

Comment: thanks for the solutions. the following commands allow me to access the functions:


`libc=cdll.atc3dg`
`libc._InitializeBIRDSystem`

Comment: @eryksun: sorry to bother you again: How do I access the constants or enum structures defined in the headers and dlls? I tried the c_int method as introduced in: http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#id18
`c_int.in_dll(libc, "BIRD_ERROR_CODES")`
or 
`c_int.in_dll(libc, "_BIRD_ERROR_CODES")`
yet it complains 
`ValueError: symbol '_BIRD_ERROR_CODES' not found`

Comment: @user2735186: For an `enum`, define integer constants, e.g. `BIRD_ERROR_SUCCESS = 0`, and continue the automatic numbering. You'll also need to define `Structure` types and the function prototypes (`argtypes`, `restype`). It's a bit tedious. Some options to automate the process are `ctypeslib` and `pycparser`. The new `cffi` library can parse C syntax in a `cdef` (using `pycparser`), as an alternative to `ctypes`.

Comment: @eryksun: do you know what would be the cffi equivalent way to ctypes for calling the __cdecl style symbol names? `libc._InitializeBIRDSystem` works under ctypes, but not for cffi.

Comment: @user2735186: Start a new `cffi` question.