# How to call a __cdel decorated function with cffi?

Tags: python, dll, python-cffi

Hi @eryksun and Python experts:

I am trying to import a dll file into python with `cffi` with the following commands:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi=FFI()
lib=ffi.dlopen('ATC3DG.DLL')
```

From a previous question about [ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554149/ctypes-load-a-dll-without-error-message-but-nothing-happened), I know that [DLL](http://www.cc.ncu.edu.tw/~auda/ATC3DG.rar) are all cdecl (thanks to @eryksun's hints), and I was able to access its functions in the following fashion:

```
from ctypes import *
lib=windll.LoadLibrary('ATC3DG.DLL')
lib._InitializeBIRDSystem
```

However, I am not sure what would be the equivalent operations in cffi. `lib._InitializeBIRDSystem` works under ctypes but not cffi. Any suggestion?

Thanks for looking into this,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols exported by atc3dg.dll use a leading underscore, which is unusual for cdecl. You'll have to add the underscore in the definitions used in `ffi.cdef`, just as you did with ctypes.

```
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef('''
enum MESSAGE_TYPE
{
    SIMPLE_MESSAGE,     // short string describing error code
    VERBOSE_MESSAGE,    // long string describing error code
};

int _InitializeBIRDSystem(void);

int _GetErrorText(
    int                 errorCode,
    char                *pBuffer,
    int                 bufferSize,
    enum MESSAGE_TYPE   type
    );
''')

lib = ffi.dlopen('atc3dg.dll')
buf = ffi.new('char[100]')

err = lib._InitializeBIRDSystem()
lib._GetErrorText(err, buf, len(buf), lib.SIMPLE_MESSAGE)
print(ffi.string(buf).decode('ascii'))

# output:
# System         : No BIRDs were found anywhere
```

---

If you have a C compiler configured, you can use `ffi.verify()`. I'm not very experienced with cffi (not yet, but it looks promising), so take this with a grain of salt.

I had to make a small change to the header. In the definition of `COMMUNICATIONS_MEDIA_PARAMETERS`, line 500 needs to add `enum` as follows:

```
enum COMMUNICATIONS_MEDIA_TYPE mediaType;
```

Also, just as an FYI, the compiler printed a few warnings, such as "conversion from '`unsigned __int64`' to '`unsigned short`', possible loss of data". I haven't followed up on this in the generated source for the extension module.

```
import os
import cffi
import subprocess

pth = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.environ['PATH'] += ';%s' % pth

# preprocess: modify this for your compiler
# Using Microsoft's cl.exe that comes with VC++.
# cdef chokes on __declspec, so define DEF_FILE.
cmd = 'cl.exe /DDEF_FILE /EP %s' % os.path.join(pth, 'atc3dg.h')
hdr = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef(hdr)

# using __declspec(dllimport) links more efficiently,
# but skipping it still works fine
lib = ffi.verify(hdr, library_dirs=[pth], libraries=['atc3dg'])
buf = ffi.new('char[100]')

err = lib.InitializeBIRDSystem()
lib.GetErrorText(err, buf, len(buf), lib.SIMPLE_MESSAGE)
print(ffi.string(buf).decode('ascii'))
# output:
# System         : No BIRDs were found anywhere
```

On the plus side, this approach avoids the leading underscore. It's an ABI detail handled by the linker when the extension module is compiled.

Comment: Thanks again for these very helpful answers. 
On my computer (64-bit win7, running a 32-bit python environment), an error message occurred for the second script at the line:
`lib = ffi.verify(hdr, library_dirs=[pth], libraries=['atc3dg'])`
I managed to get by with changing the line to:
`lib = ffi.verify(hdr, libraries=['atc3dg'])`
Don't know why though. Do I need to set-up any other path parameters for it to work with the `library_dirs` options?

Comment: I placed the 2nd script in the same directory as the header, import lib, and dll. However, it could be run from any working directory, so I added the script's directory to `PATH` for loading atc3dg.dll, and also to `library_dirs` for the compiler to find atc3dg.lib. You'll have to look into writing a proper setup.py.