# Create a DLL from a CPP file called by ctypes

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2015, ctypes

I have some functions defined in a cpp file, that is used in a game made in Python using ctypes.

I wanted to create a DLL with this cpp file, so that I could call it later in Python in Windows. For that I have been trying to use Visual Studio 2015, but I have not been able to do it.

Could you help me create the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, access your project properties by right-clicking your project and selecting `Properties`. From there go to `Configuration Properties->General` check for the field `Configuration Type` and set it to **Dynamic Library (.dll)**. That's it!

[image]

Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though, I've checked and I have that option.  I went to new project, section Visual C++, then I chose the win32 project, created an empty project and in the source section I added an existing file, my cpp file. In the Configuration Manager I chose the option x64 since I've built everything in 64 bits. Then I built the solution and I got a dll, but when I try to run my program it says that isn't able to find a function that is defined in the cpp file, so I suppose I'm doing something wrong

Comment: There's so much thing that could be wrong here, but so few details. Name mangling is different from 32 bits to 64 bits, but it doesn't seem to be an issue here. When you created your Win32 project, did you select to export symbols? It could also depend if you are compiling it into Debug or Release. Maybe there's something wrong with your code? I suggest you to post another question more specific to your current problem. And also check posts like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554149/ctypes-load-a-dll-without-error-message-but-nothing-happened?rq=1)